# Symfony 2 using salt login always returns Bad credentials

Tags: php, security, symfony, authentication, salt

if I'am using salt to decode my password using, the login always returns "Bad credentials".

I'am using Fixture to create some testdata:

```
public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
{
    $encodeFactory = $this->container->get('security.encoder_factory');

    $user = new User();
    $user->setUsername('admin');
    $user->setEmail('webmaster@aranox.de');

    $encoder = $encodeFactory->getEncoder($user);
    $user->setPassword($encoder->encodePassword('admin', $user->getSalt()));

    $user->setIsEnabled(true);

    $manager->persist($user);
    $manager->flush();

    $this->addReference('user-admin', $user);
}
```

I set up the encoding in security.yml:

```
security:
    encoders:
        Aranox\UserBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm: sha512
```

creating salt in my user-entity using:

```
...
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $password;
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $salt;

...
function __construct()
{
    $this->groups               = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->salt                 = md5(uniqid(null, true)); 
...
```

If creating no salt ($this->salt = ""), all works fine.

How can this happens?

Answer (score 5):

Please check your password field length in entity file and increase it to 255 if less because sha512 contain long string .